# Add title to JFreeChart SVG

Tags: svg, jfreechart, batik

I want to add `<title>`s to svg charts exported from JFreeChart using batik. I have read the following interesting paper http://www.svgopen.org/2009/papers/7-Enhancing_ServerSide_SVG_Generation_using_the_Batik_Extension_Handler_Mechanism/

[Alternative URL](http://www.graphicalweb.org/2009/papers/7-Enhancing_ServerSide_SVG_Generation_using_the_Batik_Extension_Handler_Mechanism/)

but I'm missing some steps. If I replace the actual Paint (an instance of Color) with (for example) TooltipPaint

```
 pie.setSectionPaint(key,new TooltipPaint("some text", "a description"));
```

I loose the information about the color, so how to proceed in the right way?

Comment: Search the relevant [forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=32) for [`TooltipPaint`](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=TooltipPaint).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now it works. The main problem was that I was passing a SVGGeneratorContext to ExtensionSVGGraphics2D. You have to create a custom SVGGeneratorContext via the ExtensionSVGGraphics2D constructor.

Needed classes: CompositePaint, TooltipPaint, ExtensionPaint, ExtensionSVGGraphics2D

How to set tooltips:

Approach 1)

```
 if(plot instanceof PiePlot){
      PiePlot pie=(PiePlot)plot;
      List keys=pie.getDataset().getKeys();
      for(int i=0;i<keys.size();i++){
        Comparable k=(Comparable)keys.get(i);
        Paint p=pie.getSectionPaint(k);
        String tooltip=((PiePlot)plot).getToolTipGenerator().generateToolTip(pie.getDataset(),k);
        TooltipPaint tooltipPaint=new TooltipPaint(tooltip,tooltip);
        p=new CompositePaint(p,tooltipPaint);
        pie.setSectionPaint(k,p);
      }
    }
```

Approach 2)
- Override drawItem Method from class PiePlot
- before the call to g2.fill set the CompositePaint

```
if(tip!=null){
   paint = new CompositePaint(paint,new TooltipPaint(tip,tip));
}
```